# Optimising function to strip honorifics from names

Tags: python, string, algorithm, performance, optimization

## Problem

I have a list of around ~1000 [honorifics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorific), see below for a sample.

Given an input string of a name, for example `"her majesty queen elizabeth windsor"`, the function should return `"elizabeth windsor"`. If there is no honorific present *at the start of the name* (to simplify the problem), the function should simple return the name itself (e.g. `elizabeth windsor` -> `elizabeth windsor`).

I have pretty intense latency constraints, so need to optimise this code as much as possible.

## Working solution

Here is my working solution, there are some additional constraints to reduce false positives (for example `lance` is both an honorific and a first name), see the unit tests:

```
def strip_honorific(source: str, honorifics: List[str]) -> str:
    source_tokens = source.split()
    if len(source_tokens) > 2:
        for honorific in honorifics:
            if source.startswith(f"{honorific} "):
                stripped_source = source[len(honorific) + 1 :]
                if len(stripped_source.split()) > 1:
                    return stripped_source
    return source
```

## Unit tests

```
def test_honorifics():
    assert strip_honorific(source="her majesty queen elizabeth windsor", honorifics = honorifics) == "elizabeth windsor"
    assert strip_honorific(source="elizabeth windsor", honorifics = honorifics) == "elizabeth windsor"
    assert strip_honorific(source="mrs elizabeth windsor", honorifics = honorifics) == "elizabeth windsor"
    assert strip_honorific(source="mrselizabeth windsor", honorifics = honorifics) == "mrselizabeth windsor"
    assert strip_honorific(source="mrselizabeth windsor", honorifics = honorifics) == "mrselizabeth windsor"
    assert strip_honorific(source="her majesty queen", honorifics = honorifics) == "her majesty queen"
    assert strip_honorific(source="her majesty queen elizabeth", honorifics = honorifics) == "her majesty queen elizabeth"
    assert strip_honorific(source="kapitan fred", honorifics = honorifics) == "kapitan fred"
    
    
test_honorifics()
```

## Benchmark

For a basic benchmark, I've used the below list of honorifics (minus the ellipses).

```
source_lst = [
    "her majesty queen elizabeth windsor",
    "mr fred wilson",
    "the rt hon nolan borak",
    "his most eminent highness simon smithson", 
    "kapteinis jurijs jakovļevs", 
    "miss nancy garland",
    "missnancy garland",
]


times = []
for _ in range(1000):
    for source in source_lst:
        t0 = time.time()
        strip_honorific(source=source, honorifics = honorifics)
        times.append(time.time() - t0)

print(f"Mean time: {sum(times)/ len(times)}s") # Mean time: 5.11584963117327e-06s
```

## Honorifics list

```
honorifics = [
    "mr", 
    "mrs", 
    "the hon",
    "the hon dr",
    "the hon lady",
    "the hon lord",
    "the hon mrs",
    "the hon sir",
    "the honourable",
    "the rt hon",
    "her majesty queen",
    "his majesty king",
    "vina",
    "flottiljamiral",
    "superintendent",
    "rabbi",
    "diraja",
    "domnul",
    "kindralleitnant",
    "countess",
    "pan",
    "khatib",
    "zur",
    "vice",
    "don",
    "flotiles",
    "dipl",
    "his most eminent highness", 
    ...
    "the reverend", 
    "archbishop", 
    "sheik", 
    "shaikh", 
    "the rt hon lord", 
    "la tres honorable"
    "ekselence", 
    "kapteinis", 
    "kapitan", 
    "excellenza"
    "mr", 
    "mrs", 
    "miss"
]
```

Comment: Start by making honorifics a set instead of a list. The set is implemented as a hashtable and the lookup time complexity is therefore O(1) instead of O(n) like for a list. Since you have a lot of lookups, this should make a difference. From this alone I get a 25% speedup.

Comment: the last 3 tests seem to be wrong, but the last 2 are definitely bad, why doesn't it remove the `kapitan` in the last one? and why doesn't `her majesty queen elizabeth` result in just `elizabeth`?

Comment: I've added some constraints to lower the likelihood of false positives, for example `if len(stripped_source.split()) > 1:`. For my use case, a false negative is preferable to a false positive, hence the last 2 unit tests seeming to be strange.

Comment: What is the intended output for "the hon lady dana"? There is the honorific "the hon lady", but since "dana" is just one word, it should not match, but then there is also the honorific "the hon", and then "lady dana" are two words. So should that second option be rejected or taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I had a doubt about how the following input should be dealt with:

"the hon lady dana"

When the honorific "the hon lady" is taken, then it doesn't match, because "dana" is just one word, but when the shorter honorific "the hon" is taken, then it does match, and "lady dana" would be the stripped version, but it would be odd to have "lady" retained, since it clearly is *part* of a longer honorific.

I would think that because of the first, longer match, no other attempt should be made, and nothing should be stripped from the input string. I took that approach in my attempts below.

I will offer two alternatives:

1. Using regex
2. Using word-based trie

Using your benchmark there wasn't much difference, but for realistic data the ratio between matches and non-matches might have some influence on total running time.

#### Regex solution

Preprocessing:

```
honorifics_re = re.compile(fr"^(?:{'|'.join(sorted(honorifics, key=len, reverse=True))}) (\S+( \S)?.*)")
```

Actual function:

```
def strip_honorific(source: str, honorifics) -> str:
    m = honorifics.match(source)
    return m[1] if m and m[2] else source
```

Call with `honorifics = honorifics_re`

#### Trie solution

Preprocessing:

```
def make_trie(honorifics):
    root = {}
    for honorific in honorifics:
        node = root
        for word in honorific.split():
            if word not in node:
                node[word] = {}
            node = node[word]
        node["$$"] = len(honorific) + 1
    return root
```

Actual function:

```
def strip_honorific(source: str, honorifics) -> str:
    node = honorifics
    for word in source.split():
        if word not in node:
            if "$$" in node:
                rest = source[node["$$"]:]
                if " " in rest:
                    return rest
            return source
        node = node[word]
    return source
```

Call with `honorifics = make_trie(honorifics)`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to improve the performance by >2x by reformatting the honorifics list into an alternative form.

```
def reformat_honorifics(honorifics):
    honorifics_by_letter_dct = {}
    for honorific in honorifics:
        honorifics_by_letter_dct[honorific[0]] = honorifics_by_letter_dct.get(honorific[0], {})
        
        honorifics_by_letter_dct[honorific[0]][len(honorific.split()[0])] = honorifics_by_letter_dct[honorific[0]].get(len(honorific.split()[0]), []) + [honorific]

    return honorifics_by_letter_dct    
    
reformatted_honorifics = reformat_honorifics(honorifics)


def strip_honorific_1(source: str, honorifics) -> str:
    source_tokens = source.split()
    if len(source_tokens) > 2:
        if honorifics.get(source_tokens[0][0]):
            if honorifics[source_tokens[0][0]].get(len(source_tokens[0])):
                for honorific in honorifics[source_tokens[0][0]].get(len(source_tokens[0])):
                    if source.startswith(f"{honorific} "):
                        stripped_source = source[len(honorific) + 1 :]
                        if len(stripped_source.split()) > 1:
                            return stripped_source
    return source
```

Mean time: 2.1538e-06s